# How to print the column name on Pandas DataFrame row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this DataFrame:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'day':['1/1/2017','1/2/2017','1/3/2017','1/4/2017','1/5/2017','1/6/2017','1/7/2017'],
                     'event':['Rain','Sunny','Snow','Snow','Rain','Sunny','Sunny'],
                   'temperature': [32, 35, 28,24,32,31,''],'windspeed':[6,7,2,7,4,2,'']})
 df
```

[image]

I am trying to find the headers for the missing values on index 6:

```
for x in df.loc[6]:
if x == '':
    print(df.columns.values)
else: print(x)
```

[image]

I have tried searching and the closest I could get was what I have now.  Ultimately I'm trying insert these values into the dataframe:  temperature = 
34, windspeed = 8.

But my first step was simply trying to build the loop/if statement that says if x=='' & [COLUMN_NAME] == 'temperature'...  and that is where I got stuck.  I'm new to python, just trying to learn Pandas.  I need to only return the column I'm on, and not a list of all the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are better ways to do this, but this works.

```
for col, val in df.loc[6].iteritems():
    if not val: # this is the same as saying "if val == '':"
        print(col)
    else:
        print(val)
```

Comment: I tried that using iterrows(), and didn't work.  Didn't think about using iteritems(). Works great!  And yes I realize there are a lot better ways to accomplish what I need to do, this is more about just learning different ways to slice and dice a dataframe. :)

Answer (score 1):

Modified from your code:

```
for i,x in enumerate(df.loc[6]):
    if x == '':
        print(df.columns[i])
    else: print(x)
```

Comment: I wish I could select 2 answers.  Having both of these answers actually helps me to see the multiple ways of achieving this same thing.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would use list comprehension as follows:

```
listOfNulls = [ind  for ind in df.loc[6].index if df.loc[6][ind] == '']
```

and when I print the `listOfNulls`, I get:

```
>>>> print(listOfNulls)
Out: ['temperature', 'windspeed']
```

The key here is it understand that df.loc[6] is a pandas `Series` which has indices. We are using the values of the `Series` to get the indices.